# Some sort of join statement?

Tags: mysql

How do I put these two queries into a single query?

```
select count(id) as cnt from {$site_id}.proofingv2_packages where active='1'
select count(id) as cnt from {$site_id}.proofingv2_package_options where active='1' and parent={$row["id"]} order by sort
```

`$row['id']` is the id field from the first query. I am trying to determine if there are any valid packages. A valid package must be active and have at least 1 active option. Running 2 queries for this doesn't seem right.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select count(id) as cnt from 
 {$site_id}.proofingv2_packages pp
 INNER JOIN
 {$site_id}.proofingv2_package_options
 pt ON pp.active = pt.Active AND
 pp.Active = 1
```

if the id is the PK or FK on the same on both tables use this query

```
 select count(id) as cnt from 
    {$site_id}.proofingv2_packages pp
    INNER JOIN {$site_id}.proofingv2_package_options pt ON pp.id= pt.id
    AND pp.Active = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Updated to: `select count(id) as cnt from {$site_id}.proofingv2_packages pp INNER JOIN {$site_id}.proofingv2_package_options pt ON pp.id= pt.parent WHERE pp.active = 1 AND pt.active = 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(count(*) > 0, 1, 0) AS isValid
FROM  {$site_id}.proofingv2_packages pp
INNER JOIN {$site_id}.proofingv2_package_options ppo ON ppo.parent = pp.id
WHERE pp.active = '1'
AND ppo.active = '1'
```

This should return 1 if there are valid packages or 0 if not